# How can I modify my boost::any like class

Tags: c++, class, boost

I'm trying to implement `boost::any` like class:

```
struct any
{
private:
struct holderBase
{
    virtual ~holderBase(){}
};

template<typename T>
struct holder : public holderBase
{
    T content;
    holder(const T& value) : content(value){}
    holder(const holder<T>& other) : content(other.content){}
};

holderBase *hl;
public:
template<typename T>
any(const T& data = T()) { hl = new holder<T>(data); }
any(const any& other) { hl = other.hl; }

template<typename T>
T get()
{
    if(holder<T>* p_hl = dynamic_cast<holder<T>*>(hl))
        return p_hl->content;
    else
        throw std::runtime_error("std::runtime_error");
}
};
```

I use a holder class (inherited by `holderBase`) to store the data.
How can I modify the `any::get()` function (or even modify the whole code) so that it doesn't need a template parameter (the `get()` function)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stating the obvious: If you don't want to return 1 particular type to the user then it needs to be templated. There's nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
template<typename T>
T get(T *ptr);
```

Similar to the C `time` function, you would return the result, as well as store it in `ptr`.

Edit: You could also override the casting operator:

```
template<typename T>
operator T()
{
   return get<T>();
}
```

Which will implicitly do what you want.

Comment: +1 for the first option, I would avoid the second at all costs. Implicit conversions are a bad idea in general, and implicit conversions to *any* type are the worst of them.